# Doing an LEFT JOIN in LINQ to Entities erroring when trying to get data from second table

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` but when I try to access any column from the second table I get the error "the name 'f' does not exist in the current context". I though I was doing the join code right based off some answers I found via Google but apparently not. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
model = (from s in db.Sections
        join f in db.Files
        on s.LogoFileID equals f.ID into s_f
        where s.RouteName == RouteName
        select new GameSectionVM
        {
            GameTitle = s.Title,
            LogoFileName = f.FileName,
            Synopsis = s.Synopsis
        }).Single();
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a left join to me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin

Comment: Can i also mention that .Single() is going to throw an error if you get more than 1 result from the join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is not a left join. It's an inner join. As described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) you need to add a temporary table to join with:

```
var model = (from s in db.Sections
         join f in db.Files
           on s.LogoFileID equals f.ID into s_f
         where s.RouteName == RouteName
         from x in s_f.DefaultIfEmpty() // this is the line you're missing
         select new GameSectionVM
         {
             GameTitle = s.Title,    
             LogoFileName = x.FileName ?? string.empty,  // Select from x
             Synopsis = s.Synopsis
         }).Single();
```

*Note: As mentioned by [@failedprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1862333/failedprogramming) in the comments, using `Single()` here is dangerous as the join is very likely to return more than 1 item. I would recommend applying an appropriate ordering statement and switching to `FirstOrDefault()`.*

*Note2: When selecting from `x` you may not be able to use the null coalescing operator ?? because it may not have a SQL translation. If that's the case, switch to use the traditional ternary `= x.FileName == null ? string.Empty : x.FileName,`*

Comment: Even doing a copy and paste of your code gives the same error.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: Perhaps if you shared with us the actual error our efforts could have more direction.

Comment: The error is what I stated in the first post "The name 'f' does not exist in the current context" This is a compile time error that VS 2013 is throwing.

Comment: Oh, actually that seems to be obvious actually. It's a problem with the select. I will post an edit. `s` and `f` do not exist in the context of this from block. We need to use `x` (in my code version).